# Liberty Server not show up after installation

Tags: spring, websphere-liberty

I installed SpringToolSuite4 (version 4.8.0, Build Id: 202009151856) on MacOS Catalina. From within the suite, I installed "WebShpere Application Server Liberty Server Adapter". The suite was restarted, but Liberty Server is not showing under IBM on the "New Server" window. How to get Liberty Server visible? Thank you!

Comment: I would suggest that you post this question on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/).  This question is not really in scope for Stack Overflow, as it is not a programming problem.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse 2020.09 by any chance?

Comment: I just posted the question on ServerFault. Thanks!

Comment: I tried IBM's Eclipse Oxygen and it works in MacOS Catalina. The issue with Liberty Server/SpringToolSuite4 showed up after I upgraded MacOS from Mojave to Catalina.